# Taking integral into a function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to take integral of a function $\int_{\alpha}f_{n+1}(R,i(1+\alpha),s)dF_{\alpha}$ but I have some problems with my code running time, is there any rule that I can use to take my integral inside my f function? $f_{n+1}(R,\int_{\alpha}i(1+\alpha),s)dF_{\alpha}$
By the ways I am taking a definite integral.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it.